# Starting container process caused "exec: \\"tail -f /dev/null\\": stat tail -f /dev/null: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, tail

Because I am trying to keep a container running I specified the "*tail -f /dev/null*" as **command** in the docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  serviceName:
  .
  .
  .

  command:
    - tail -f /dev/null
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  .
  .
  .
```

After I run ***docker-compose up*** I get the following error:

ERROR: for serviceName  Cannot start service serviceName: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused ***"exec: \"tail -f /dev/null\": stat tail -f /dev/null: no such file or directory"***: unknown'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

However if I start the container from the CLI with the same command it works perfectly.

What actually happens under the hood and how can I make this work ?

Linux version of the container is:
**4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs**.

The host machine uses Windows 10 OS and the Docker for Windows version is: 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513),
docker compose 1.21.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would suggest trying:

```
command:
  - tail
  - -f
  - /dev/null
```

From the error message docker compose will consider the first element of the command array as the command name (including the spaces etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

in docker-compose.yml
This worked for me